My Nginx VPS not serving any website anymore
I have an Ubuntu with nginx and a laravel app (php8.1).
It stopped serving websites after accidentally changing ownership of all folders to root.
I managed to restore cloudpanel and my domain for a bit (changed ownership of each), but my domain stopped working after redeploying again using root (needs to fixed as well)
Now, whenever I enter my domain in any web browser, I get either Access denied or 
The screenshot also goes for any new website I initiate using cloudpanel even if it has an index.php.
No matter what I do I can't get past this anymore, nginx is now running as www-data, ownership of my website is under dakaken its under /home/dakaken/.... php-8.1 is run by root even tho I specifically set the user to dakaken as well in its config.
The biggest problem also is, I can't find the 500 logs error anywhere. nginx/error.log and phpfpm logs are not saying anything regarding this.
Ps: the only thing being served correctly is cloudpanel.
ChatGPT also wasn't helpful, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Restore from backup. Your system is fubar and unlikely to be recoverable.

Seems that is the only solution, thank you for your help. It is back online now.
